# Asynchronous EJB scheduling

Tags: scheduling, ejb-3.1

I'm wondering how asynchronous EJB methods are scheduled onto the underlying plateform (SMP/NUMA plateform for example) ?

Can anyone describe the scheduling middleware (I'm not familiar with EJB).

Answer (score 2):

EJB as a spec doesn't say how this should be exactly implemented, giving implementations the free hand to choose how to do this.

That said, the implementations I've seen simply use a thread pool. It functions pretty much like an executor service does in Java SE. A call to an `@Asynchronous` methods results in a task being put in a queue, which is serviced by said thread pool.

SMP/NUMA properties are not directly influenced by EJB, but depend on how the underlying operating system handles threads within a single process.